# Will a Graphics Card requiring 500W work fine with 650W PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I assume so, but it never hurts to make sure.

The card I'm talking about is the Nvidia GeForce GTX 670. I currently use the GTX 460 SE, which recommends at least 450W of system power. I may end up going with the GTX 660, which requires the same amount of power as my 460 SE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it requires "at least 450w" then anything above 450w will work.  I am going to downvote this question for the lack of research on your part.

Answer (score 2):

That graphics card draws 170W max. It recommends that the system power supply is 500W. 
[specs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-670/specifications)

As long as your power supply is capable of 500+ watts and the added draw of the other components is less than 330W, your system is withing recommended spec.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the power requirements for the rest of your system are less than 150W then theoretically "yes". Though 500W for a graphics card seems a lot. Are you sure that the requirement wasn't for a **power supply** rated at at least 500W?

In that case a 650W PSU is more than enough.

In general, when dealing with power it's advisable to have a buffer between the maximum power requirements of your system and the peak power (which is the value quoted) that the PSU can deliver.

So add up the requirements of your system:

- Motherboard
- Hard drives
- Optical drives
- Graphics card

Add a buffer (10%?) and if that comes to less than 650W you should be OK.

Comment: If it is a PCI-e graphics card then it is not allowed to draw more than 300 Watt (Up to 75 W via motherboard, up to 75 Watt via 6 pins, up to 150 Watt via 8 pin. And 2x8 pin is not yet standarised). So YOu are right. The `500Watt-ish` requirement does mean 'Max GPU power plus max power for the rest of the system'.